# Modelling a simple graph with nodes and edges.

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was trying to visualize a graph using d3.js. I tried two layouts, bundle-radial and force.

Bundle-radial didn't work because every node requires a parent node and it isn't suitable for graph visualization.

For the force layout, the script hangs. Maybe it's because there are many nodes and edges in this graph. Also i don't need the simulation that comes with the force layout.

Is there any other layout in d3.js that i could try using ?

Comment: How many nodes and edges are we talking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need simulation, you can use the force layout statically. After calling [force.start](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-start), call [force.tick](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-tick) some number of times followed by [force.stop](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-start) to cease the simulation:

```
// Run the layout a fixed number of times.
// The ideal number of times scales with graph complexity.
// Of course, don't run too long—you'll hang the page!
force.start();
for (var i = n; i > 0; --i) force.tick();
force.stop();
```

In some cases, it may help to initialize the node positions deterministically to encourage the simulation to converge quickly on a good solution. If you don't initialize the positions, the force layout will initialize them randomly, so it can be a bit unpredictable. For example, here I initialize the nodes along the diagonal:

```
// Initialize the positions deterministically, for better results.
var n = nodes.length;
nodes.forEach(function(d, i) { d.x = d.y = width / n * i; });
```

Lastly, if you're using a static layout, consider using [fisheye distortion](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) to still allow interactive exploration.